# Changes to Observable Collection not updating DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have an observable collection in my viewmodel as follows..Not perfect but just code that looks as below populating an observable collection and bind it to the datagrid. I also have two buttons beside the datagrid one for upcommand and one for downcommand. When I click the upbutton everything works fine in which the selected row moves up and the sequence order is getting updated, Observable Collection is also getting updated. But the changes are not being bound to the DataGrid. Similarly for the downcommand. My view is below. The commands are working just fine only the view is not being updated. .Please help.
Issue is with observable collection, move up and move down.

ViewModel:

```
public class JobConfigurationViewModel : BindableBase
{


    public JobConfigurationLogic JobConfigurationLogic =
        new JobConfigurationLogic(new JobConfigurationResultsRepository());

    public SrcDestConfigurationLogic SrcDestConfigurationLogic =
        new SrcDestConfigurationLogic(new SrcDestCofigurationRepository());


    private string _enterprise;

    public string Enterprise
    {
        get { return _enterprise; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _enterprise, value); }
    }

    private int currentJobID;
    private int currentSequence;
    private int previousJobID;
    private int previousSequence;
    private string _site;

    public string Site
    {
        get { return _site; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _site, value); }
    }

    private int _siteID;

    public int SiteID
    {
        get { return _siteID; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _siteID, value); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<JobConfigurationResults> _jobEntities;

    public ObservableCollection<JobConfigurationResults> JobEntities
    {
        get { return _jobEntities; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _jobEntities, value);
            //JobEntities.CollectionChanged += JobEntities_CollectionChanged;
            OnPropertyChanged("JobEntities");
        }
    }

    //void JobEntities_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    if (e.OldItems != null)
    //    {
    //        foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
    //        {
    //            this.GetJobConfigurationResults();
    //        }
    //    }
    //}

    //Source System List for Job
    private List<SourceSiteSystem> _lstJobSrcSystems;

    public List<SourceSiteSystem> LstJobSrcSystems
    {
        get { return _lstJobSrcSystems; }
        set
        {
            //Using bindable base setproperty method instead of older inotify prop changed method
            SetProperty(ref _lstJobSrcSystems, value);
        }
    }

    //Deestination  System List for Job
    private List<DestinationSiteSystem> _lstJobDestSystems;

    public List<DestinationSiteSystem> LstJobDestSystems
    {
        get { return _lstJobDestSystems; }
        set
        {
            //Using bindable base setproperty method instead of older inotify prop changed method
            SetProperty(ref _lstJobDestSystems, value);
        }
    }

    //the Selected Source Site system ID 
    private int _selectedSrcSiteSystemId = 0;

    public int SelectedSrcSiteSystemId
    {
        get { return _selectedSrcSiteSystemId; }
        set
        {
            //Using bindable base setproperty method instead of older inotify prop changed method
            SetProperty(ref _selectedSrcSiteSystemId, value);
        }
    }

    //the Selected Source Site system from the dropdown
    private SourceSiteSystem _selectedSrcSiteSystem;

    public SourceSiteSystem SelectedSrcSiteSystem
    {
        get { return _selectedSrcSiteSystem; }
        set
        {
            //Using bindable base setproperty method instead of older inotify prop changed method
            if (value != null)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedSrcSiteSystem, value);
                SelectedSrcSiteSystemId = SelectedSrcSiteSystem.SiteSystemId;
            }
        }
    }

    //the Selected Destination Site system ID 
    private int _selectedDestSiteSystemId = 0;

    public int SelectedDestSiteSystemId
    {
        get { return _selectedDestSiteSystemId; }
        set
        {
            //Using bindable base setproperty method instead of older inotify prop changed method
            SetProperty(ref _selectedDestSiteSystemId, value);
        }
    }

    //the Selected Destination Site system from the dropdown
    private DestinationSiteSystem _selectedDestSiteSystem;

    public DestinationSiteSystem SelectedDestSiteSystem
    {
        get { return _selectedDestSiteSystem; }
        set
        {
            //Using bindable base setproperty method instead of older inotify prop changed method
            if (value != null)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedDestSiteSystem, value);
                SelectedDestSiteSystemId = SelectedDestSiteSystem.SiteSystemId;
            }
        }
    }

    private JobConfigurationResults _jeJobConfigurationResults;

    public JobConfigurationResults JEJobConfigurationResults
    {
        get { return _jeJobConfigurationResults; }
        set { _jeJobConfigurationResults = value; }
    }

    private List<JobTaskConfiguration> _taskSelectionList = new List<JobTaskConfiguration>();

    private CancellationTokenSource _source;

    private RelayCommand<object> _commandSaveInstance;
    private RelayCommand<object> _hyperlinkInstance;
    private RelayCommand<object> _commandRunJob;
    private RelayCommand<object> _upCommand;
    private RelayCommand<object> _downCommand;
    private IEventAggregator _aggregator;


    /// <summary>
    /// This is a Subscriber to the Event published by EnterpriseViewModel
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="agg"></param>
    public JobConfigurationViewModel(IEventAggregator agg)
    {
        _aggregator = agg;
        PubSubEvent<Message> evt = _aggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<Message>>();
        evt.Subscribe(message => Enterprise = message.Enterprise.ToString(), ThreadOption.BackgroundThread);
        evt.Subscribe(message => Site = message.Site.ToString(), ThreadOption.BackgroundThread);
        evt.Subscribe(message => SiteID = message.SiteID, ThreadOption.BackgroundThread);
        //evt.Unsubscribe();
        StartPopulate();
    }

    private async void StartPopulate()
    {
        await TaskPopulate();
    }

    //This is to ensure that the publisher has published the data that is needed for display in this workspace
    private bool TaskProc()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        PubSubEvent<Message> evt = _aggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<Message>>();
        evt.Subscribe(message => Enterprise = message.Enterprise.ToString(), ThreadOption.BackgroundThread);
        evt.Subscribe(message => Site = message.Site.ToString(), ThreadOption.BackgroundThread);
        evt.Subscribe(message => SiteID = message.SiteID, ThreadOption.BackgroundThread);
        return DoPopulate();
    }

    private Task<bool> TaskPopulate()
    {
        _source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(TaskProc, _source.Token);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method handles the populating of the Source and Destination Dropdowns and the Job entity and Task Datagrid
    ///   This is mainly driven by the Site selected in the previous workspace
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>

    private bool DoPopulate()
    {
        PopulateSourceDestinations(this.SiteID);

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// this method displays all entities and tasks for the site.
    /// This is done async so that the Publisher thread is not held up
    /// </summary>
    public void GetJobConfigurationResults()
    {
        if (SelectedSrcSiteSystem == null)
        {
            SelectedSrcSiteSystem = LstJobSrcSystems[0];
        }
        if (SelectedDestSiteSystem == null)
        {
            SelectedDestSiteSystem = LstJobDestSystems[0];
        }
        SelectedSrcSiteSystemId = SelectedSrcSiteSystem.SiteSystemId;
        SelectedDestSiteSystemId = SelectedDestSiteSystem.SiteSystemId;
        var jobConfigurationResults = new JobConfigurationResults
        {
            SourceId = SelectedSrcSiteSystemId,
            DestinationId = SelectedDestSiteSystemId
        };
        JobEntities = new ObservableCollection<JobConfigurationResults>();
        JobEntities = JobConfigurationLogic.GetResults(jobConfigurationResults.SourceId,
            jobConfigurationResults.DestinationId);
        _taskSelectionList = new List<JobTaskConfiguration>(JobEntities.Count * 3);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// //Adding a method to pupulate the Source and Destination dropdown lists. 
    /// This is done async so that the Publisher thread is not held up
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// 
    public async void PopulateSourceDestinations(int siteId)
    {
        this.LstJobSrcSystems = SrcDestConfigurationLogic.LoadSourceSiteSystems(siteId);
        this.LstJobDestSystems = SrcDestConfigurationLogic.LoadDestinationSystems(siteId);
        GetJobConfigurationResults();
    }

    public ICommand HyperlinkCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_hyperlinkInstance == null)
                _hyperlinkInstance = new RelayCommand<object>(openDialog);
            return _hyperlinkInstance;
        }
    }

    private void openDialog(object obj)
    {
        JobConfigurationResults results = obj as JobConfigurationResults;
        JEJobConfigurationResults = JobEntities.SingleOrDefault(x => x.JobEntityId == results.JobEntityId);

    }

    public ICommand CommandSave
    {
        get
        {
            if (_commandSaveInstance == null)
                _commandSaveInstance = new RelayCommand<object>(saveJobConfigurationChanges);
            return _commandSaveInstance;
        }
    }

    public ICommand CommandRunJob
    {
        get { return _commandRunJob ?? (_commandRunJob = new RelayCommand<object>(RunJob)); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// this saves all the changes in the selection made by the user 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ob"></param>
    public void saveJobConfigurationChanges(object ob)
    {
        foreach (var job in JobEntities)
        {
            JobConfigurationLogic.UpdateSequence(job.SequenceOrder, job.JobEntityId); //Save Sequence Changes
            int jobEntityId = job.JobEntityId;
            foreach (var task in job.TaskDetails)
            {
                int id = task.JobTask_ID;
                bool isSelected = task.IsSelected;
                _taskSelectionList.Add(task);
            }
        }
        JobConfigurationLogic.UpdateTaskSelection(_taskSelectionList);
    }


    public ICommand UpCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_upCommand == null)
                _upCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(MoveUp);
            return _upCommand;
        }
    }

    private void MoveUp(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            JobConfigurationResults results = obj as JobConfigurationResults;
            currentJobID = results.JobEntityId;
            currentSequence = results.SequenceOrder - 1;

            JobConfigurationResults previousResult =
                JobEntities.FirstOrDefault(n => n.SequenceOrder == currentSequence);
            try
            {
                previousJobID = previousResult.JobId;
                previousSequence = previousResult.SequenceOrder;

                int newindex = JobEntities.IndexOf(results);
                int oldindex = JobEntities.IndexOf(previousResult);

                JobEntities[newindex].SequenceOrder = previousResult.SequenceOrder;
                JobEntities[oldindex].SequenceOrder = results.SequenceOrder + 1;


                //foreach (var i in JobEntities)
                //{
                //    MessageBox.Show(i.EntityName + " " + i.SequenceOrder);
                //}
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have reached the top");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select a row first");
        }
    }



    public ICommand DownCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_downCommand == null)
                _downCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(MoveDown);
            return _downCommand;
        }
    }

    private void MoveDown(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            JobConfigurationResults results = obj as JobConfigurationResults;
            currentJobID = results.JobEntityId;
            currentSequence = results.SequenceOrder + 1;

            JobConfigurationResults previousResult =
                JobEntities.FirstOrDefault(n => n.SequenceOrder == currentSequence);
            try
            {
                previousJobID = previousResult.JobId;
                previousSequence = previousResult.SequenceOrder;


                int newindex = JobEntities.IndexOf(results);
                int oldindex = JobEntities.IndexOf(previousResult);

                JobEntities[newindex].SequenceOrder = previousResult.SequenceOrder;
                JobEntities[oldindex].SequenceOrder = results.SequenceOrder - 1;

                foreach (var i in JobEntities)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(i.EntityName + " " + i.SequenceOrder);
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot move further down");
            }

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select a row first");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute an etl job using the current job id
    /// </summary>
    private void RunJob(object obj)
    {
        JobEngine jobEngine = new JobEngine();
        var jobId = JobEntities[0].JobId;
        jobEngine.ProcessJob(jobId);
    }
}
```

View.XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate1">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate2">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Bisque" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.14*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TextBlock>
                <Label FontSize="16">Enterprise:</Label>
                <Label Name="lblEnterprise"  FontSize="16" Content="{Binding Enterprise}" />
                <Label FontSize="16">Site:</Label>
                <Label Name="lblSite" FontSize="16" Content="{Binding Site}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock>
                <Label FontSize="16">Source System:</Label>
                <ComboBox Name="CmbSource" Margin="3" SelectedIndex="0" Width="220" ItemsSource="{Binding LstJobSrcSystems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSrcSiteSystem, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath ="SourceSystemType"></ComboBox>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2,2,14,2">
            <Label FontSize="16">Destination System:</Label>
            <ComboBox Name="CmbDestination" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="2" Width="220" ItemsSource="{Binding LstJobDestSystems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDestSiteSystem, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath ="DestinationSystemType"></ComboBox>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,2,0,46" Grid.RowSpan="3">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="{Binding ElementName=dgEntities,Path=Width}" Margin="35,48,60,48" Height="{Binding ElementName=grd,Path=Height}">
                <Grid Name="grd" Height="30" Width="{Binding ElementName=JobConfigCol,Path=Width}" ShowGridLines="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="c1" Width="82*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="c2" Width="83*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="c3" Width="83*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="c4" Width="96*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Margin="24,0,78,0" Width="62" Content="Extract"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Margin="40,0,38,0" Width="88" Content="Transform"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Margin="66,0,54,0" Width="46" Content="Load"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <DataGrid x:Name="dgEntities" Width="690" Height="370" Margin="40,-48,65,-8" CanUserAddRows="false" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.DataContext>
                    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="CollectionViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=JobEntities,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
                    </CollectionViewSource>
                </DataGrid.DataContext>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="138" MaxWidth="138">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Margin="5" Content="{Binding TaskDetails[0].Status,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.HyperlinkCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgEntities,Path=SelectedItem}" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick" >
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
                                             <ContentPresenter />
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=c1,Path=ActualWidth}">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <CheckBox Name="chkHeaderExtract" Checked="ChkHeaderExtract_OnChecked" Unchecked="ChkHeaderExtract_OnUnchecked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>

                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="chkExtract" IsChecked="{Binding TaskDetails[0].IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></CheckBox>

                            </DataTemplate>

                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="138" MaxWidth="138">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Margin="5" Content="{Binding TaskDetails[1].Status,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.HyperlinkCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgEntities,Path=SelectedItem}" Cursor="Hand" Foreground="Blue" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick_2" >
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
                                             <ContentPresenter />
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=c2,Path=ActualWidth}">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <CheckBox Name="chkHeaderTransform" Checked="ChkHeaderTransform_OnChecked" Unchecked="ChkHeaderTransform_OnUnchecked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="chkTransform" IsChecked="{Binding TaskDetails[1].IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></CheckBox>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="138" MaxWidth="138">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Margin="5" Content="{Binding TaskDetails[2].Status,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.HyperlinkCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgEntities,Path=SelectedItem}" Cursor="Hand" Foreground="Blue" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick" >
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
                                             <ContentPresenter />
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>

                                </Button>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=c3,Path=ActualWidth}">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <CheckBox Name="chkHeaderLoad" Checked="ChkHeaderLoad_OnChecked" Unchecked="ChkHeaderLoad_OnUnchecked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="chkLoad" IsChecked="{Binding TaskDetails[2].IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></CheckBox>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EntityName}"  Header="Entity" Width="{Binding ElementName=c4,Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>



            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-388,43,0" Height="108">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"><InlineUIContainer>
                        <Button Height="40" Width="40" x:Name="btnup" Command="{Binding UpCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgEntities,Path=SelectedItem}" Click="Btnup_OnClick">
                            <Image x:Name="Up" Source="../Images/up.jpg" Height="40" />
                        </Button>
                    </InlineUIContainer></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,2"><InlineUIContainer>
                        <Button Height="40" Width="40" x:Name="btndown" Command="{Binding DownCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgEntities,Path=SelectedItem}" Click="btndown_Click">
                            <Image x:Name="Down" Source="../Images/Down.jpg" Height="40" />
                        </Button>
                    </InlineUIContainer></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Name="tbldemo" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Name="btnRun" Height="30" Width="90" FontSize="18" Margin="9" Command="{Binding CommandRunJob}" >Run</Button>
                <Button Name="btnSave" Height="30" Width="90" FontSize="18" Margin="9" Command="{Binding CommandSave, Mode=OneWay}">Save</Button>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left">
               <Button Name="btnclose" Height="30" Width="90" FontSize="18" Margin="19,9">Close</Button>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CS: Im saying CollectionViewSource.View.Refresh();

Comment: The pasted code seems incomplete, can you please add also the rest?

Comment: And line it up to the left

Comment: Please view the entire code. I have edited my post with entire code.

Comment: Please debug and check if JobEntities' setter is being called when it should. This method OnPropertyChanged("JobEntities"); should update the view as soon as JobEntities change

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are on the right track. the reason your view is not updating when you are changing properties in the collection from the view model, is because while you are making use of ObservableCollection for it to work correctly in the way you are describing, you will need to make sure that the type that you are binding to in the collection implements INotifyProperyChanged. Once you do this, the ObservableCollection will receive this message and in turn notify your view of the changes and ultimately causing a view update.

so in your case you would need to make sure that the type JobConfigurationResults implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

For a reference, you can view this link and towards the bottom of the page you will find the note describing what I am suggesting. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365(v=vs.110).aspx